# SonarQube 5.6 - update plugin behind proxy (HTTPS) and web context

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

Using the update center behind a proxy with an associated context gives me this known error:

```
Fail to download the plugin (css, version 3.1) from https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases/download/3.1/sonar-css-plugin-3.1.jar
Error is : Fail to download: https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases/download/3.1/sonar-css-plugin-3.1.jar (no proxy)
```

I've seen I must provide `http.proxyHost/Port` in the `sonar.properties` configuration file, but I've got problems with web context (assigned by `sonar.web.context=/mycontext`).

Two cases:

http.proxyHost=myhost/mycontext => fails because tries connection with myhost/mycontext:port

```
Fail to download the plugin (css, version 3.1) from https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases/download/3.1/sonar-css-plugin-3.1.jar
Error is : Fail to download: https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases/download/3.1/sonar-css-plugin-3.1.jar (HTTP proxy: <myhost>/<mycontext>:443)
```

http.proxyHost=myhost => fails and sonarqube don't show any plugin

Note: Ports are 80 y 443 (standard), https uses same host.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Comment: No, my proxy hasn't authentication.